# No documentation for built-in object type review (see video.rates action) or news.read ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, built-in

On the FB documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type), i can't see the built-in object "Review", but this object is used in the action 'video.rates' => http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.rates

So, this built-in object exist or not ?

Other question : i want to trigger an action when an user read a review. (like the og built-in action news.read). But, problem : where is the built-in action news.read ? (see documentation : developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type) Facebook have desactivate this action ? Can i use it for publishing a "read a review" or i have to make my own 'read' action ?

Comment: Same problem no documentation for og.recommends ( see : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ near Like/Follow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the built in object "Review" does exist for now, but considering how frequently facebook makes changes, I dont know how longer will it  be available. (btw there is no warning about it being deprecated or removed in [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)).

But if you really want to use it, here is a sample (you can try it out in [graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer))

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.rates?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
rating:value=3.1415926535&
rating:scale=42&
rating:normalized_value=3.1415926535&
review=http://samples.ogp.me/467235199955838
```

Here review is a reference to a [self hosted review object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/) (in layman's term: it is the page that contains the meta tags for review object) but I think it can be an object id in case of the object being created by the [Object API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/). But one thing to keep in mind is that the review object must have an meta tag `og:object` reference to its video or movie object (url). (Personally I also keep a `review:target` reference to the same url, just in case.)

As far as the second question goes I dont think you can do that. Facebook considers it content consumption and wont allow your custom action to pass review. You can only publish stories when users have explicitly performed some action on your site.

Comment: Recently facebook started complaining about og:object property in review types, so rather use review:target only.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem! They have already removed the news.reads action, so I'm not sure if we are already allowed to make a custom read action.. It wasn't allowed before. Also, when you try to use news.reads, the action does not appear on the timeline, only on your activity log.

Answer (score 0):

Add this namespace xmlns:review="http://ogp.me/ns/review#" to html tag on your page and check it out all params by this link http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/review